# Windows 10 Task Bar stops responding when switching to new user, and after restarting computer. Restarting Windows Explorer doesn't fix it

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

The task bar in Windows 10 has started to act up whenever I switch to a new user on my computer. It shows no icons and when hovered over the spinny wheel shows. I can still open a file explorer window while the task bar is messed up. This was not fixed after restarting Windows Explorer through Task Manager. Windows Explorer was not showing up as not responding in task manager.

While testing, I found that it does something similar after restarting (through menu options). When I log in after a restart, the task bar is unresponsive, and all the other symptoms I've described are present, except that icons do show up.

I have a temporary workaround to fix the problem. If I force shut down the computer by holding down the power button, then turn the computer back on, the problem does not occur.

I recently installed MSI Afterburner and Asus DisplayWidget. Could one of these be responsible?

Comment: If you suspect MSI or ASUS software, forcefully end their process, and see if the problem still exists

Comment: If the additional software is a coincidence, try doing a Windows 10 Repair Install (Microsoft Media Creation Link).